# how to select unselected (not :selected) items in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for that selector that is the inverse of `:selected`.

It has to select every checkbox that are not selected.

I have tired this way, but it does not worked:

```
$("#cont").find("input[type=checkbox]:not(:selected)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selector `:selected` is used primarily for options in `<select>`. For checkboxes and radio buttons you should use `:checked` selector.

```
$("#cont").find("input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)");
```

Answer (score 1):

Checked property is of input

```
$("#cont").find("input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)");
```